# python Tkinter ListBox callback: passing a class-instance-specific callback

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the strange thing:
Say, you have a tk.Button (RUN) inside a class and you can specify a callback like

```
self.RUN["command"] =  self.run
```

This refers to a function inside the class, which has access to all members.
In essence, the callback sees a class instance.

You can also create a tk.ListBox. The machinery of getting the selection involves events.
You cannot pass an instance-of-a-class-function as above.
The callback sees only the opaque event/widget things in Tk.

You can do

```
def CurSelect(evt) :
    ...
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelect)
```

but there is no way to pass more than the event.

So, when you have several ListBoxes running in the mainloop, what happens?
How can you map event/widget to the class instance that owns the event/widget?

Sure, you could make up some global maps. (Ugly, tried, I hate it.)
Anything better out there?

Comment: Please include more of your actual code in the question for a concrete answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use lambda to pass arguments.

```
arguments = []
widget.bind("<>", lambda event, arg=arguments: cur_select(event, arg))

def cur_select(event, arg):
    return
```

Also, naming convention for Python function: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yes, it works. Actually, I figured out myself. (I am new to Python and things do not come naturally.)